# Object reference is not set to an object when try to implement abstract factory

Tags: c#, design-patterns, abstract-factory

I am developing my first game in Unity and I am trying to apply the `Abstract Factory` pattern to create the Monsters of the game. I have an Interface that all Monsters should implement:

```
interface IMonster
    {
        void setSpeed(float s);
        float getSpeed();
        void SetMonsterPosition(Vector2 pos);
        Vector2 GetMonsterPosition();
        void DestroyMonster();
        void MoveMonster();
    }
```

I have a concrete Monster

```
public class Monster2 : MonoBehaviour, IMonster
{

    ....

    public Monster2()
    {
        speed = Random.Range(0.05f, 0.15f);
        monster = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Monster2"));
        float height = Random.Range(0, Screen.height);
        Vector2 MonsterStartingPosition = new Vector2(Screen.width, height);
        MonsterStartingPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(MonsterStartingPosition);
        monster.transform.position = MonsterStartingPosition;
    }

    ....

}
```

And I want to create a Factory class that has a method which returns a new Monster object so I will be able later to create concrete Monster objects randomly. I wrote the following:

```
 class MonsterFactory
    {

        public IMonster getMonster()
        {
            return new Monster2();
        }
    }
```

And I am trying to use this Factory in my main like this:

```
 private IMonster monster;
    private MonsterFactory myMonsterFactory;

    void Start () {
        monster = myMonsterFactory.getMonster();
    }
```

When I am trying to run the game I get the following error `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `myMonsterFactory` is null?

Comment: you should declare your MonsterFactory and the getMonster methods as static.

Comment: @DavidBrabant thank you David, I fixed it like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `GetMonster` method in the `MonsterFactory` class to be static

```
class MonsterFactory
{
    public static IMonster GetMonster()
    {
        return new Monster2();
    }
}
```

In your `Main` method call it

```
private IMonster monster;

void Start() 
{
    monster = MonsterFactory.GetMonster();
}
```